# How Global HTTP Proxy works internally?

Tags: ios, http, proxy

I understand that question could be a little bit outside of SO scope.

I wonder, how does Global HTTP proxy differentiate between HTTP and non HTTP traffic?

- Does it check whether connection is made to a port 80?
- Does it do some level of traffic inspection?
- Does it filter only calls which go through specific API's (like NSURLRequest)?

I want to make sure that application which I will be writing will work correctly with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I talked to Apple Tech Support and they gave me info that proxy is applied automatically to:

- NSURLConnection and everything what is based on it (as example UIWebView)
- CFHTTPStream supports proxy, but it's not automatically applied to it. So, proxy settings could be read through API's defined in CFProxySupport.h
- Anything below CFHTTPStream doe not have support for proxies (ase example CFSocketStream, BSD sockets and so on).